# Differential not returning the answer

Tags: pattern-matching, tensors

I have the following set of rules for differentiation.

```
 SetAttributes[δ, Orderless]
    δ /: δ[a_, b_] h_[former___, b_, latter___] := 
     h[former, a, latter]
    δ[a_, a_] = 2*M;
    
    Format[δ[a_, b_]] := Subscript[δ, a, b]
    Format[x[a_, b_]] := Subscript[x, a, b]
$Assumptions = 
 x ∈ Matrices[{2*M, 2*M}, Reals, Antisymmetric[{1, 2}]]
x[arg__] /; ! OrderedQ@{arg} := Signature@{arg} x @@ Sort@{arg} 
Format[x[arg__]] := Subscript[x, arg]

myD[-a_, o_] := -myD[a, o];
myD[a_, -o_] := -myD[a, o];

myD[a_ + n_, o_] := myD[a, o] + myD[n, o];
myD[a_ b_, o_] := b myD[a, o] + a myD[b, o];
myD[x_[k_, l_], 
   x_[v_, g_]] := δ[k, v] δ[l, g] - δ[k, 
     g] δ[l, v];
myD[_?NumericQ, _] = 0;

myD[I*δ[k_, l_], x_[d_, r_]] := 0;
myD[δ[k_, l_], x_[s_, n_]] := 0;
myD[δ[k_, l_], -x_[β_, α_]] := 0;

myD[δ[k_, l_]*δ[k_, l_], x[s_, n_]] := 0;
myD[Exp[P_], x_[d_, r_]] := Exp[P]*myD[P, x[d, r]];
```

To Evaluate:

```
FT = (x[j, i]*x[j,i])
WeiS = Exp[-FT]

myD[WeiS, x[u,n]]
```

It's not returning the answer. What I am expecting is:
[image: dd]

Comment: Think carefully about why the following "doesn't work": `a^2 /. a_ b_ :> 1`

Comment: @xzczd I didn't understand what you meant. Can you explain

Comment: …Do you know what is `/.`? If not, please check the document by pressing **F1**.

Comment: @xzczd yup Replace all I didn't understand why a^2 /. a_ b_ :> 1 used here

Comment: Remember what's `FT` in your code?

Comment: @xzczd It's the square of x[j,i]

Comment: OK, then why do you expect the rules will work for `FT`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123915/discussion-between-jasmine-and-xzczd).

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @xzczd, I figured out that the issue was caused by an external package.

By adding

```
myD[a_^2, o_] := 2*a myD[a, o]
```

we can sort the issue.